# How to remove a column from a file and write the result in same file using shell scripting?

Tags: unix

I have a file (a.txt) which is like below,

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7
a|b|c|d|m|n|o
e|f|g|h|p|q|r
i|j|k|l|s|t|u
```

I want to remove the col3 from the a.txt and write the result in the same a.txt file. Now the a.txt file will be look like,

```
col1|col2|col4|col5|col6|col7
a|b|d|m|n|o
e|f|h|p|q|r
i|j|l|s|t|u
```

I have done the removal portion using 'cut' command but not able to write in the same file without using 'mv' command. like - `cut -d'|' -f1-2,4- a.txt`

So, could anyone please help me out, how will i keep the same file with the new value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For all practical purposes, you have to write a new file without the column to be removed, and then move the new file over the old file.  Some commands have a way to do that for you behind the scenes (`sed -i.bak -e …` for example), but many do not.  You could do the job with `sed` instead of `cut`, but it is easier to see what's going on with `cut`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk -i inplace  -F'|' '{OFS="|"; $3=""; gsub(/\|\|/,"|",$0)}1' a.txt
```

Demo:

```
$cat a.txt 
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7
a|b|c|d|m|n|o
e|f|g|h|p|q|r
i|j|k|l|s|t|u

$awk -i inplace  -F'|' '{OFS="|"; $3=""; gsub(/\|\|/,"|",$0)}1' a.txt 
$cat a.txt 
col1|col2|col4|col5|col6|col7
a|b|d|m|n|o
e|f|h|p|q|r
i|j|l|s|t|u
|
$
```

Explanation:

`-i inplace` < -- Make changes to file

`-F'|'`  <--  Set input filed seprator as  `|`

`OFS="|"` < -- Set putput field seprator as `|`

`$3=""` <-- Set column 3 as empty

`gsub(/\|\|/,"|",$0)`  <--  Replace  `||` with `|`

**Edit: Using `sed`**

`sed -i  's/[^|]*|//3' a.txt`

Demo

```
$cat a.txt 
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7
a|b|c|d|m|n|o
e|f|g|h|p|q|r
i|j|k|l|s|t|u
$ sed -i  's/[^|]*|//3' a.txt
$cat a.txt 
col1|col2|col4|col5|col6|col7
a|b|d|m|n|o
e|f|h|p|q|r
i|j|l|s|t|u
$
```

Explanation"

```
$echo "a|b|d|m|n|o" | sed -e's/[^|]*|/(&)/'
(a|)b|d|m|n|o
$
```

`[^|]` -- Any charactet excep `|`
`*` -- Zero oe more occurence
`3` 3rd occurence

Comment: Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...
Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...
POSIX options:          GNU long options:
        -f progfile             --file=progfile
        -F fs                   --field-separator=fs
  
To report bugs, see node `Bugs' in `gawk.info', which is
section `Reporting Problems and Bugs' in the printed version.
gawk is a pattern scanning and processing language.
By default it reads standard input and writes standard output.

Comment: Replace awk with gawk

Comment: Still not working.. shall we use any other command instead of -i inplace?

Comment: Try `sed -i  's/[^|]*|//3' a.txt`

Comment: Welcome. I have updated the answers explaining  the pattern match.

Comment: Hi Digvijay, 

I am facing one issue for this command {sed -i  's/[^|]*|//3' a.txt}. If the delimiter is "~" instead of "|"  then it is not working. Could you please help me out from this.

Comment: Replace `|` with `~`

Comment: col1~col2~col3~col4~col5~col6~col7
a~b~c~d~m~n~o
e~f~g~h~p~q~r
i~j~k~l~s~t~u

and i have run the below command,

 sed -i 's/[^~]*|//3' a.txt

But it is not able to discard the 3rd column.

I have tried this one echo "a~b~d~m~n" | sed -e's/[^~]*|//3' also, but it won't discard anything.

Comment: Hi @user3040157 You have to replace both `|`  try `sed   's/[^~]*~//3'`

Comment: Demo `$echo 'col1~col2~col3~col4~col5~col6~col7' | sed 's/[^~]*~//3'
col1~col2~col4~col5~col6~col7
$
`